# Constructing chrono::time_point

Tags: c++, c++11, std

Given two split values, seconds since epoch and µs, is one of the following preferable?

```
auto timestamp = system_clock::time_point(seconds(time_seconds) + microseconds(time_us));
```

or

```
auto timestamp = system_clock::time_point(seconds(time_seconds)) + microseconds(time_us);
```

Comment: Neither is preferable to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter at all which one of those two you choose.  It does however pay to have `time_seconds` and `time_us` as 64-bit integers--this cuts the whole operation from 5 instructions to 3 on x86_64.  See: https://godbolt.org/g/8u1pYn

Comment: Beautiful answer. Face-palm for not godbolting myself. The types are from external code I do not control.